# How to show two vf page in single page

Tags: visualforce, rerender, selectoption, outputpanel, embedded

I have create following two visualforce page and I would like to show in single VF page based on the option button. how to do?

VF Page: 
firstvf
secondvf

thirdvf
**Code:**

```
<apex:page>

<apex:outputpanel render="true">
firstvf
</apex:outputpanel>

<apex:outputpanel render="false">
secondvf
</apex:outputpanel>


</apex:page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apex:include` tag. Please refer to the [Salesforce Docs](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm) for [further details](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/Content/reusing_pages_3.htm). If you want to dynamically display the pages based on the option selected, here is a simple solution for that:

```
    <apex:page>
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" onclick="displayPage();">option1</input> <input type="checkbox" id="option2" onclick="displayPage();"> option2 </input>
<div id="option1Page" style="display:none;">
<apex:include pageName="vfpage1"/>
</div>

<div id="option2Page" style="display:none;">
 <apex:include pageName="vfpage2"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayPage() {
    if (document.getElementById('option1').checked ) {
     document.getElementById('option1Page').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('option1').checked=true;
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('option1').checked=false;
      document.getElementById('option1Page').style.display = "none";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option2').checked ) 
    {
     document.getElementById('option2Page').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('option2').checked=true;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('option2').checked=false;
    document.getElementById('option2Page').style.display = "none";
    }
    }

   </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you make the code please am really beginner.

Comment: check the updated answer. really recommend to have a look at the at the links as well.

Comment: Really thanks how to create the optionbutton on the top and render based on the optionbox?

Comment: what kind of option button, can you pleas elaborate your use case?

Comment: the page should show the two option like show-firstpage and show-secondpage. if we click the firstoption, the first page should show.

Comment: i have updated the answer with the solution, let me know if that helps.